# WPF DataTemplate access to Resources within same ResourceDictionary

Tags: wpf, resources, datatemplate

Simplified, I have a ResourceDictionary which contains a DataTemplate and a ViewModel-Class.

```
<ResourceDictionary>
    <DataTemplate DataType="Whatever">
        <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource MyViewModel}, Path=SomeGlobalData}" />
    </DataTemplate>

    <MyViewModelClass x:Key="MyViewModel" />
</ResourceDictionary>
```

Of course the Binding won't work (it'll fire exceptions) because the DataType won't have the resource 'MyViewModel'. But in the VisualTree the "thing" that gets DataTemplated is a child of an object which has the ResourceDictionary merged to its Resources, so there might be a way to access it within runtime.

So my question is: Is there any clean way to access 'MyViewModel' within the DataTemplate?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is the order these resources are instantiated and the fact that you use `StaticResource` vs `DynamicResource`.

A `StaticResource` provides a value for any XAML property attribute by looking up a reference to an already defined resource. Try to find out more on the subject.

So please move your view model above the data template if you still plan on using `StaticResource`.

Comment: If you still have problems please provide more information, but if you want to see my test project, take a look at:
http://sdrv.ms/M8OfB9
It's a skydrive link.